# Rendering multiple Rmd files in the same directory to individual pdfs (R, bookdown)

Tags: r, bookdown

I have several Rmarkdown (Rmd) files in the same directory, and want to render them into *individual* pdf files using `bookdown::render_book`. I normally use `knitr::knit` for that, but would like to take advantage of the cross-referencing in bookdown. But I would still like to have one Rmd file for each pdf file, and have them live independently in the same directory.

According to [section 12.4 of the bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/bookdown-output.html#a-single-document) I can use `output: bookdown::pdf_document2` in the yaml header to generate a single pdf from an Rmd file. However, `bookdown::render_book` always combines all Rmd files that it finds in the directory, which is not what I want.

Is there an option in the yaml header or in the `bookdown::render_book` function where I can tell it to ignore all other Rmd files in the directory?

I know there is an option `rmd_files` I can specify in the file `_bookdown.yaml` but I don't know how this would work with multiple Rmd files, and I would also like to avoid having to maintain a separate yml file.